# Convert rows to columns and sum with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table with columns `ID`, `WorkingDate` and `AmountReceived` where data is show as

```
ID    WorkingDate     AmountReceived
-------------------------------------
1     13/April/2021   201999.01 
2     14/Arpil/2021     1099.02
```

Now, I am trying to show it like

```
13/April/2021      14/April/2021    15/April/2021      
--------------------------------------------------
201999.01          1099.02          102.09
```

I tried this

```
select AmountReceived, WorkingDate
from Orders o

select distinct o.WorkingDate, sum(AmountReceived) over (partition by WorkingDate) as total 
from Orders o
group by WorkingDate, AmountReceived
```

But it throws an aggregate error.

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: Where is the `15/Apr/2021` with `102.09` comes from ?

Comment: @Squirrel I have edited the query and error is gone. it was a grouping issue. but still it's in rows, not columns

f

Comment: comes from table Orders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) operator, you can achieve what you want

```
 select *
 from
 (
    select o.WorkingDate, o.AmountReceived
    from   Orders o
 ) o
 pivot
 (
     sum(AmountReceived)
     for WorkingDate in ([2021-04-13], [2021-04-14], [2021-04-15])
 ) p
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '（'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '）'

Comment: but the working dates are like not fixed, it could be anything from the table. i mean any date

Comment: fixed the typo. As for the dates, if it is not fixed, you will need to use dynamic sql